# Appended fields in a form not aligned

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, append

How can I make the add function add the fields aligned before the submit button, is it ok the way I'm doing it and I'm just missing something to get added fields aligned, or must I make the function different?:
https://jsfiddle.net/ab5v3dss/4/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="formHabitaciones" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Agregar Hotel</legend>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 pull-left">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label pull-right" for="ID_del_evento">Evento:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <select name="ID_del_evento" id="ID_del_evento" class="form-control input-md pull-left">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php 
     foreach ($results as $row) {
       echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_del_evento'] . "'"; 
       if (!empty($_GET['ID_del_evento'])) {
       if ($row['ID_del_evento'] == $_GET['ID_del_evento']) {
        echo " selected";
        }
      };
       echo ">" . $row['Nombre'] . "</option>";
     }
     ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label pull-right" for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <input type="Nombre" class="form-control input-md pull-left" id="Nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre" name="Nombre">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label pull-right" for="Tarifa_de_transporte">Tarifa de transpore:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-md pull-left" id="Tarifa_de_transporte" placeholder="Ingresa la Tarifa_de_transporte" name="Tarifa_de_transporte">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Habitaciones</label>
            <div class="voca">

              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="habitacion0].ocupacion" placeholder="Ocupacion" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="habitacion[0].categoria" placeholder="Categoria" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="habitacion[0].camas" placeholder="Camas" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="habitacion[0].tarifa" placeholder="Tarifa" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar mas
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.col-md-6 form:first'),
      currentEntry = $(this).parents('.voca:first'),
      newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.btn-add:not(:last)')
      .removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')

    .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Quitar   ');
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

This is the best I could:
[best I could](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylaX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea is correct, but you have some coding errors. For example, you are using commas instead of semicolons on a couple of lines.

I have created a pen that does a simpler version of what you want. If you use this as a starting point, you can add your specific features step by step and make sure it works at each step.

```
<div class="one">
    <p>one</p>
    <button class="append"><p>append</p></button>
    <br><br>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.append').click(function() {
      $('.submit').before($('.one p:first').clone());
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/wahhabb/pen/ZKoqqJ

Answer (score 0):

I have created one class and append extras items with in it. Please check this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab5v3dss/9/)** and let me know.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.extras'),
      currentEntry = $(this).parents('.voca:first').addClass('clearfix'),
      newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.btn-add:not(:last)')
      .removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')

    .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Quitar');
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```